# React + Material UI testing with jest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, material-ui

I use this library for UI: https://github.com/callemall/material-ui and use Jest for unit testing.

But when I require a component use that library I got the error syntax error. Other components are with jest.

```
 - SyntaxError: /Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/src/js/components/CampaignStepViewer.js: /Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/material-ui/src/index.js: /Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/material-ui/src/js/app-bar.jsx: /Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/material-ui/src/js/icon-button.jsx: Unexpected token {
        at Contextify.sandbox.run (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/node_modules/jsdom/node_modules/contextify/lib/contextify.js:12:24)
        at JSDomEnvironment.runSourceText (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/JSDomEnvironment.js:106:22)
        at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:341:23)
        at Loader._execModule (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:245:9)
        at Loader.requireModule (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:900:12)
        at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:921:17)
        at /Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/material-ui/src/js/app-bar.jsx:3:16
        at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:357:17)
        at Loader._execModule (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:245:9)
        at Loader.requireModule (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:900:12)
        at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:921:17)
        at /Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/material-ui/src/index.js:2:11
        at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:357:17)
        at Loader._execModule (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:245:9)
        at Loader.requireModule (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:900:12)
        at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:921:17)
        at /Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/src/js/components/CampaignStepViewer.js:4:11
        at Object.runContentWithLocalBindings (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/lib/utils.js:357:17)
        at Loader._execModule (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:245:9)
        at Loader.requireModule (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:900:12)
        at Loader.requireModuleOrMock (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/src/HasteModuleLoader/HasteModuleLoader.js:921:17)
        at Spec.<anonymous> (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/src/js/components/__tests__/CampaignStepViewer-test.js:10:26)
        at jasmine.Block.execute (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:1065:17)
        at jasmine.Queue.next_ (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2098:31)
        at null._onTimeout (/Users/cuongcua/Work/AgencyRevolution/frontend.react.revolution/node_modules/jest-cli/vendor/jasmine/jasmine-1.3.0.js:2088:18)
        at Timer.listOnTimeout [as ontimeout] (timers.js:112:15)
```

I have update jest at package.json below:

```
"unmockedModulePathPatterns": [
      "/node_modules/debug",
      "/node_modules/react",
      "/node_modules/material-ui",
      "/node_modules"
    ]
```

It does not work.

Comment: Please include the full error you're getting.

Comment: I have already updated my error

Answer (score 3):

You have to use `ES6 transform` in your preprocessor for `jest`.

```
var ReactTools = require('react-tools');
module.exports = {
    process: function(src) {
        return ReactTools.transform(src, {
            harmony: true
        });
    }
};
```